# codeigniter session data `all_userdata` and `set_userdata`

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have the below codeigniter code in my app that is working 100% but I don't know why.

**part of my controller syntax**

```
 if($this->input->post()){ 

      $data = array(
       'customer' =>$this->input->post('customer'),
       'period' =>$this->input->post('period'),
       'buom' =>$this->input->post('buom'),
      // 'creditlimit' =>$this->input->post('buom'),
       'creditlimit' => $this->sales_model->get_creditlimit($this->input->post('customer'))
      );

 $this->session->set_userdata($data);
  }

$this->load->view('sales/new_blank_order_lines',$this->session->all_userdata());
```

I do not understand the link between `set_userdata($data);` and `$this->session->all_userdata()`

what is `set_userdata` to `all_userdata`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: what you are doing here can also be achieved by an array that will be empty at the beginning. SO i think Session storing thing can be replaced with array that can be passed to view on post checking

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as the documentation says:

for all_userdata:

`$this->session->all_userdata()` means that all the available data is put in an array like so.

```
Array
(
    [session_id] => 4a5a5dca22728fb0a84364eeb405b601
    [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7;
    [last_activity] => 1303142623
)
```

for set_userdata:

Adding Custom Session Data

> A useful aspect of the session array is that you can add your own data
>   to it and it will be stored in the user's cookie. Why would you want
>   to do this? Here's one example:
>
> Let's say a particular user logs into your site. Once authenticated,
>   you could add their username and email address to the session cookie,
>   making that data globally available to you without having to run a
>   database query when you need it.
>
> To add your data to the session array involves passing an array
>   containing your new data to this function:

```
$this->session->set_userdata($array);
```

Where $array is an associative array containing your new data. Here's an example:

```
$newdata = array(
                   'username'  => 'johndoe',
                   'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
                   'logged_in' => TRUE
               );

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

Read more [HERE](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 1):

*all_userdata* returns an array of all userdata, it would return something like this:

```
Array
(
    [session_id] => 4a5a5dca22728fb0a84364eeb405b601
    [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7;
    [last_activity] => 1303142623
)
```

*set_userdata* sets custom session data.

The reason this works is because CodeIgniter is able to identify your session through *all_userdata*

Hopes this helps, don't hesitate to ask further questions =)

Answer (score 1):

Adding a reference to my comment at top

```
$data = array();
if($this->input->post()){ 
    $data = array(
    'customer' =>$this->input->post('customer'),
    'period' =>$this->input->post('period'),
    'buom' =>$this->input->post('buom'),
    // 'creditlimit' =>$this->input->post('buom'),
    'creditlimit' => $this->sales_model->get_creditlimit($this->input->post('customer'))
    );
}
if(count($data)>0)
{
    $this->load->view('sales/new_blank_order_lines',$data);
}
else
{
    $this->load->view('sales/new_blank_order_lines');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Manish, would the all_userdata array still be available to the view even though not explicitly passed to the view? Thanks a million.

Comment: My Pleasure.

Yes it can be achieved using `session` but it will cost more than to the pass the way CI framework provides. You can [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535024/codeigniter-best-practice-for-view-accessing-session) and [here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/100587/#508051)