# How to use session_data in codeigniter throughout Website without including in particular view

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Is there any other best way to use session_data in website.

How i set session in my project:

```
$sess_array = array('id' => $row->user_id,'name'=>$row->user_name,'email'=>$row->email,'condition'=>'','balance'=>$row->balance,'did_alloted'=>$row->did_alloted,'create_date'=>$row->create_date);
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
```

when it comes to controller:

```
$data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
$data['name'] = $session_data['name'];
$data['email'] = $session_data['email'];
$data['balance']=$session_data['balance'];
$data['did_alloted']=$session_data['did_alloted'];
$data['create_date']=$session_data['create_date'];
$this->load->view('san-reception', $data);
```

and in my `view`. I use `<?php echo $name ?>` to get session_data.

So is there any method by which i can directly access session_data in `view` without including as `$data`.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535024/codeigniter-best-practice-for-view-accessing-session

Comment: for global accessing of session data you could make one controller and define all session data stuff there and then allowing other controller to extend this controller

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi - can u please xplain with code ?

Comment: for you it's will be easy to define constant in application/config/constants.php/ as define('SESSION_DATA',$this->session->userdata('logged_in'));

Comment: i try to include hiresame in my constant.php but website goes down.blank white page error.

Comment: there may be other possible conflicts....

Answer (score 1):

$this->session->userdata('logged_in'); will be available directly in views and hence you just need to assigned this to a variable and then use that as array like bellow.

```
   $userdata=$this->session->userdata('logged_in');
```

now variable $userdata contain all array field that you set in controller and hence you can use it as $userdata['id'], $userdata['name'] etc

Comment: I know that i can access session_data like this : **$session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in'); $cust_id = $session_data['id'];** but again i have to use this **$session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');** first.

Comment: Something like making it global and i dont have call again n agin.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $data['session_data']=$this->session->user_data('logged_in');
}

public function some_function(){
    $data['dummy']="";
    $this->load->view('someview3',$data)
}
public function some_function1(){
    $data['dummy']="";
    $this->load->view('someview1',$data)
}

public function some_function2(){
    $data['dummy']="";
    $this->load->view('someview2',$data)
}
```

If you assign that into the constructor then it will call by automatically whenever a function calls in the controller.

you can view it in you view page by,

```
print_r($session_data);
```